# Regex expression to help count only the zeros in a string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to count the number of 0s in a string of numbers. Not exactly just the character 0, but the number zero. e.g. I want to count 0, 0.0, 0.000 etc. The numbers will be separated by spaces, e.g.:

```
1.0 5.0 1 5.4 12 0.1 14.2675 0.0 0.00005
```

A simple search for `" 0"` in the string nearly does the job (I have to first insert a leading space in the string for this to work - in case the first number is a zero). However it doesn't work for numbers in the form `0.x` e.g. `0.1`, `0.02` etc. I suppose I need to check for `0` and see if there is a decimal point and then non-zero numbers after it, but I have no idea how to do that. Something like:

`" 0*|(0\\.(?!\\[1-9\\]))"`

Anyone have any ideas how I might accomplish this? Using a regular expression preferably. Or if it it's easier, I'm happy to count the number of non-zero elements. Thank you.

NOTE: I'm using `split` in Java to do this (split the string using the regular expression and then count with `.length()`).

Comment: Probably not a great application for regex overall, but have you tried "(^|\\s)([0.]+)(\\s|$)"?  Will only really work for well-formed numbers without exponent.  I don't think `split` will give you the right answer if you have two zeros in a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
(?<=^|\s)[0.]+(?=\s|$)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=^|\s) # Assert position after a space or the start of the string
[0.]+     # Match one or more zeroes/decimal points
(?=\s|$)  # Assert position before a space or the end of the string
```

Remember to double the backslashes in Java strings.

Comment: Yes of course. If the input can be as malformed as this, that regex is too simple. Then use `-?0+(?:\.0+)?` instead of `[0.]+`.

Comment: Sorry could you explain what you mean in your last comment? What case was Antti referring to?

Comment: Well, my original regex will also treat `.` or `0.` or `.0` or even `....` as zero. The one in my comment insists on a starting `0` and if there is a decimal point, there has to be at least one `0` after it. Moral: Define clearly what you want to match, and what you don't want to match.

Comment: I may as well use the more restrictive version, although I don't expect my input to be that messed up. I've tested your solution and it works perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You should instead split by whitespace and use Double.parseDouble() on each fragment, then if it indeed is a double, compare it to 0.

```
String[] parts = numbers.split("\\s+");
int numZeros = 0;
for (String s: parts) {
    try {
        if (Double.parseDouble(s) == 0) {
            numZeros ++;
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

There is no easy solution for the regex anyway. The easiest thought would be to use the \b boundary operator, but it fails badly. Also, the Double.parseDouble means that things like -0 are supported too.

Answer (score 1):

`split()` is not the solution to this problem, though it can be *part* of the solution, as Antti's answer demonstrated.  You'll find it much easier to match the zero-valued numbers with `find()` in a loop and count the matches, like this:

```
String s = "1.0 5.0 1 5.4 12 0.1 14.2675 0.0 0.00005 0. .0 0000 -0.0";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\S)-?(?:0+(?:\\.?0*)|\\.0+)(?!\\S)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
int n = 0;

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("%n%s ", m.group());
    n++;
}
System.out.printf("%n%n%d zeroes total%n", n);
```

output:

```
0.0
0.
.0
0000
-0.0

5 zeroes total
```

This is how Tim meant for you to use the regex in his answer, too (I think). Breaking down *my* regex, we have:

- `(?<!\\S)` is a negative lookbehind that matches a position that's not preceded by a non-whitespace character.  It's equivalent to Tim's positive lookbehind, `(?<=^|\s)`, which explicitly matches the beginning of the string or right after a whitespace character.
- `-?(?:0+(?:\\.?0*)|\\.0+)` matches an optional minus sign followed by at least one zero and at most one decimal point.
- `(?!\\S)` is equivalent to `(?=\s|$)` - it matches right before a whitespace character or at the end of the string.

The lookbehind and lookahead ensure that you always match the whole token, just like you would if you were splitting on whitespace.  Without those, it would also match zeros that are part of a non-zero tokens like `1230.0456`.

---

**EDIT** (in response to a comment): My main objection to using `split()` is that it's needlessly convoluted.  You're creating an array of strings comprising all the parts of the string you don't care about, then doing some math on the array's length to get the information you want.  Sure it's only one line of code, but it does a very poor job of communicating its intent.  Anyone who's not not already familiar with the idiom could have a very difficult time sussing out what it does.

Then there's the trailing empty tokens issue: if you use the split technique on my revised sample string you'll get a count of `4`, not `5`.  That's because the last chunk of the string matches the split regex, meaning the last *token* should be an empty string.  But Java (following Perl's lead) silently drops trailing empty tokens by default.  You can override that behavior by passing a negative integer as the second argument, but what if you forget to do that?  It's a very easy mistake to make, and potentially a very difficult one to troubleshoot.

As for performance, the two approaches are virtually identical in speed (I don't know about memory they use).  It's not likely to be a problem when working with reasonably-sized texts.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Why is this preferable to using `split` do you mind me asking? I can count the zeros in a single line `numberString.split((?<=^|\s)[0.]+(?=\s|$)).length - 1` that, apart from the regex itself, is fairly straight forward to me. Is there some performance (or other) benefit to your solution?